# passing value of select to jQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have select control and input with jQuery UI autocomplete.

```
<select name="labels">
   ...some options
</select>

<input type="attr_type_input" class="attr_autocomplete ui-autocomplete-input">
<input type="attr_value_input" class="attr_autocomplete ui-autocomplete-input">
```

The values shown in autocomplete should depend on the value of select.

My javascript code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( ".attr_autocomplete" ).each(function(){
    var type=$(this).attr("type");
    $(this).autocomplete( { 
        serviceUrl: '?', 
        params: { 
            action: 'attr_autocomplete',
            type:type,
            label:$("select[name=labels]").val()
        }
    }); 
});
});
```

The problem is that label value passed to server is always the same, even if I change the select. As far as I understand this data structure is formed once on page load.

The question is - how to pass **actual** value of select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, this structure is being initialised with the starting value of the select on page load.  You can switch to using a function for the `source` parameter:

```
$(".attr_autocomplete" ).each(function(){
    var type=$(this).attr("type");
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function(req, autoCallback) {
            $.get('?', {
                term: req.term,
                action: 'attr_autocomplete',
                type:type,
                label:$("select[name=labels]").val()         
            }, function(response) {
                //perform any transforms needed on the data, then:
                autoCallback(response);
                //autoCallback is expecting an array of strings to display
            });
        }
    }); 
});
```

This function is then executed whenever the autocomplete wants data, and so it will read the value of the select each time, rather than when it's initialised.

Comment: Thanks, James. But hen I replace my code with yours, it sends request to the url of the webpage, instead of url provided in `get` function

Comment: @Lecko It shouldn't... are you sure? I assume you've replaced the `?` with an actual url?

Comment: finally I've solved this puzzle. My colleagues has modified the source code of plugin :( thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you are not retrieving the value of select after change

try this way

```
$("select[name=labels]").change(function(){
var changeValue=this.value;
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gevurzgy/)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and came up with this solution. Just another way to handle it.

If you want to have an autocomplete result set based on the value in another field in the form you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#alpha').change(function(){setLibraryAutoComplete();});
    setLibraryAutoComplete();
});
function setLibraryAutoComplete(){
    $('#beta').autocomplete({source: "TypeAhead?param1=ABC&param2="+$("#alpha").val()});
}
```

This sets up the auto complete on page load with the value from the field but then also causes the autocomplete call to update any time the source field value changes.